# MiPi Camera and Ubuntu Linux: New kernel 6.5 no longer working

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad, webcam

I followed the steps here (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lenovo) to get my MiPi camera working on my Thinkpad X1Gen10 with Ubuntu 22.04.

These steps work under 6.2:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-modules-ipu6-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-modules-ivsc-generic-hwe-22.04 (For generic kernel, like 6.2.0-32-generic)
$ sudo apt install linux-modules-ipu6-oem-22.04c linux-modules-ivsc-oem-22.04c (For oem kernel, like 6.1.0-1021-oem)
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6 (This ppa is still in development, might be not stable, in future you don't need this step)
$ sudo apt install libcamhal0
$ sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6 (the ppa will keep updating packages from upstream, might be broken)
$ sudo reboot
```

This worked fine with kernel 6.2, but now fails when booting with the newest kernel with version 6.5.0.14.14. Camera is not starting anymore and I get a black screen instead of the camera image in any application.

Is there a fix for 6.5 on the way?

Thank You!

UPDATE: There is no fix yet, Intel is moving at glacier speed on this:

https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers/issues/204

## EDIT:

running `sudo gst-launch-1.0 icamerasrc ! autovideosink`
outputs

```
[01-19 23:06:16.237] CamHAL[ERR] Malformed ET range in exposure time range configuration
[01-19 23:06:16.237] CamHAL[ERR] Parse AE eExposure time range failed
[01-19 23:06:16.237] CamHAL[ERR] Malformed ET range in exposure time range configuration
[01-19 23:06:16.237] CamHAL[ERR] Parse AE gain range failed
[01-19 23:06:16.238] CamHAL[ERR] Malformed ET range in exposure time range configuration
[01-19 23:06:16.238] CamHAL[ERR] Parse AE eExposure time range failed
[01-19 23:06:16.238] CamHAL[ERR] Malformed ET range in exposure time range configuration
[01-19 23:06:16.238] CamHAL[ERR] Parse AE gain range failed
[01-19 23:06:16.239] CamHAL[ERR] Malformed ET range in exposure time range configuration
[01-19 23:06:16.239] CamHAL[ERR] Parse AE eExposure time range failed
```

...

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
[01-19 23:06:18.506] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov13b10.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.509] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov13b10.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.511] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.511] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov13b10.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.511] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov13b10.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.512] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.512] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov8856.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.514] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov8856.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.514] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.514] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov8856.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.514] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov8856.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.515] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.515] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov01a10.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.517] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov01a10.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.518] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.518] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov01a10.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.518] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov01a10.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.519] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.519] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_1BG203N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.521] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_1BG203N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.521] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.521] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_1SG204N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.523] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_1SG204N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.523] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.523] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_CIFME14_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.525] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_CIFME14_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.525] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.525] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_1BG203N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.525] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_1BG203N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.526] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.526] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_1SG204N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.526] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_1SG204N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.526] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.526] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_CIFME14_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.526] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV02C10_CIFME14_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.527] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.527] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV2740_CJFLE23_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.529] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV2740_CJFLE23_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.529] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.529] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HM2170_1SG205N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.531] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HM2170_1SG205N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.532] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.532] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HM2170_CJFME18_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.534] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HM2170_CJFME18_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.534] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.534] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HM2170_1SG205N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.534] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HM2170_1SG205N3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.535] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.535] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HM2170_CJFME18_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.535] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HM2170_CJFME18_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.535] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.535] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HI556_1BG502T3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.538] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HI556_1BG502T3_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.538] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.538] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HI556_CJFLE25_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.540] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name HI556_CJFLE25_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.541] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.541] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov01a1s.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.543] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name ov01a1s.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.545] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.545] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV08A10_YHUT_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.547] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name OV08A10_YHUT_ADL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.548] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.548] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.550] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.550] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.550] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.550] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.550] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.550] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.550] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.551] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.551] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.551] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.551] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.551] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.551] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.552] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.553] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name IMX390_HDR_TGL.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.554] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.554] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.557] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.557] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.557] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.557] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.557] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.557] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.557] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] aiqb file name AR0234_TGL_10bits.aiqb
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[ERR] invalid media format, default value used.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.558] CamHAL[INF] (null), media format in tuning: 0, media format for aic 0.
[01-19 23:06:18.559] CamHAL[ERR] Failed to find DevName for cameraId: 0, get video node: ov13b10 , devname: /dev/v4l-subdev1
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
[01-19 23:06:18.586] CamHAL[ERR] Get entity fail for calling getEntityById
[01-19 23:06:18.586] CamHAL[ERR] Get entity fail for calling getEntityById
[01-19 23:06:18.586] CamHAL[ERR] setup Link ov13b10  [-1:0] ==> Intel IPU6 CSI-2  [-1x0] enable 1 failed.
[01-19 23:06:18.586] CamHAL[ERR] set MediaCtlConf McLink failed: ret = -1
[01-19 23:06:18.586] CamHAL[ERR] set up mediaCtl failed
[01-19 23:06:18.586] CamHAL[ERR] @configure Device Configure failed
[01-19 23:06:18.586] CamHAL[ERR] failed to config streams.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/Gstcamerasrc:camerasrc0: src pad: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstcambasesrc.cpp(3143): gst_cam_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/Gstcamerasrc:camerasrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.016210934
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Comment: btw booting into the old 6.2 kernel resolves the issue. So camera is working under 6.2.

Comment: Please file a bug report for this issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the elements of the solution you've tried in the post itself rather than relying on a link to the guide you followed. We need to understand what steps you took specifically and the error messages you got in the process as they will help us better diagnose your problem.

Comment: added the steps used before

Comment: > Please file a bug report...


I did, I wrote to oem-bugs@lists.canonical.com and posted directly to the Lenovo Forums: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Ubuntu/MiPi-Camera-and-Ubuntu-Linux-New-kernel-6-5-new-problems/m-p/5282319

Comment: I am not even able to get his to work under 6.2. But following those instructions, I do get the camera recognised at least. e.g. success when I go here: https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html. But I also get a black screen in any applications....

Comment: Wow now it also broke under 6.2, since today it breaks with borth kernels, argh

Comment: For 6.2 it seems to break randomly, very nice, see also:
https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers/issues/187

Answer (score 0):

Work on getting this camera working under linux is ongoing, and the modules you have installed are likely unstable as they are in development mode. I have sometimes found the MIPI camera works and sometimes it doesn't. The best guide I've found for ubuntu is here: https://dshedd.com/2023/07/18/fixing-lenovos-mipi-camera-problems-on-ubuntu-22-04/ and the advice is to disable the repository containing the various bits you've installed, once you've gotten it to work. That way, a future update won't break your system. So, keep checking whether it works (my system on a Lenovo x1 yoga currently works on zoom but not using the test page here https://mozilla.github.io/webrtc-landing/gum_test.html or on cheese). Then, once it is working well enough, yank the chord, via "sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:oem-solutions-group/intel-ipu6"

Comment: Unfortunately, following all the steps does not work, I have a camera that just creates a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```bash
sudo apt install linux-modules-ipu6-oem-22.04d linux-modules-ivsc-oem-22.04d
```

Works for me on
`6.5.0-1018-oem` on x1-yoga (gen8), though not consistently.

Note : `*-22.04d` (instead of `*-22.04c`).